# CreateProcessWithTokenW winapi return false but no reason why

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, process, token

I am New to winapi and I am trying to run a process with system privileges.

Lot of people suggested to use the Function CreateProcessWithTokenW.

I wrote the falling code:

```
$run = @"

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public Int32 cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public Int32 dwX;
    public Int32 dwY;
    public Int32 dwXSize;
    public Int32 dwYSize;
    public Int32 dwXCountChars;
    public Int32 dwYCountChars;
    public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int16 wShowWindow;
    public Int16 cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

public struct ProcessInformation
{
    public IntPtr process;
    public IntPtr thread;
    public int    processId;
    public int    threadId;
}

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags, string 
lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string 
lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int    Length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool   bInheritHandle;
}


public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL 
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="DuplicateTokenEx",SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess, ref 
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel, int 
TokenType, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr 
TokenHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken);

"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $run -Namespace "token" -Name "run"
$si = New-Object token.run+STARTUPINFO
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($si)
$si.lpReserved = $null

$pi = New-Object token.run+ProcessInformation

$processPath = $env:ComSpec
[uint32]$GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000
[uint32]$CREATE_NO_WINDOW =  0x08000000
[uint32]$NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020
[uint32]$CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400
$TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 2

$hprocess = (Get-Process -Name lsass).Handle
$htoken = New-Object System.IntPtr
[token.run]::OpenProcessToken($hprocess,$TOKEN_DUPLICATE, [ref]$htoken)
$DupToken = New-Object System.IntPtr

$sa = New-Object token.run+SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$sa.bInheritHandle = $true
$sa.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($sa)
$sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = [System.IntPtr]::Zero

$CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010

[token.run]::DuplicateTokenEx($htoken,$GENERIC_ALL,[ref]$sa, 
[token.run+SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL]::SecurityImpersonation,1,[ref]$DupToken)
[token.run]::ImpersonateLoggedOnUser($DupToken)
[token.run]::CreateProcessWithTokenW($DupToken,0,$null,$processPath,$CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
[System.IntPtr]::Zero,$null,[ref]$si,[ref]$pi)
```

this code returns: True,True,True,False

It means that it managed to OpenProcessToken and Duplicate it and Impersonate to be System.

But for some reason it didn't manage to Create a process with the given token.
(moreover if I run

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()
```

, it shows 0, that means that the operation finished successfully).

Can someone please explain why it is failing??

Comment: Maybe you are running into [this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw): *"Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. **If a required DLL cannot be located or fails to initialize, the process is terminated.** To get the termination status of a process, call [GetExitCodeProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess)."*

Comment: So you suggest that I will try to run GetExitCodeProcess and maybe I will get more info?

Comment: @IInspectable - and so what ? this is absolute unrelated to `CreateProcessWithTokenW`. and impossible call `GetExitCodeProcess` because we have not process handle. process not created at all. but not fail initialize

Comment: So what do you suggest to do, how can I determine what the problem is?

Comment: you bad call `GetLastError()` - if `CreateProcessWithTokenW` fail - it **not** return 0. i not view in your code any error checks

Comment: i tried after calling CreateProcessWithTokenW to write this code: $x = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error().    And then pasting $x, and $x shows only 0

Comment: Is there maybe a way to check for the error??, Or maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: i dont know c#. but if `CreateProcessWithTokenW` fail `GetLastError` will return nonzero

Comment: also call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` not need here

Comment: so for some reason when I call GetLastError it shows 0, and I don't know why

Comment: again - you bad call it or bad check `CreateProcessWithTokenW` return value

Comment: As I see I bad check the GetLastErrorCode() but do you know how to use it with powershell using the following code above?

Comment: i dont know powershell and c#. if want - can paste your test *exe* file - and will be very easy look under debugger where it fail. i be also for test use self process handle instead *lsass.exe*, also use `$processPath` as application name but not command line, and you not need use `$sa` here, and remove `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` call. so - do this (for self process instead lsass) and etc, and paste *exe* file

Comment: Thank you very much I solved it. I switched Where the $ProcessPath should be, and in the lpcurrentdirectory i added the string "c:\windows\system32" and it worked

Comment: *lpcurrentdirectory* is optional parameter, it can be 0. `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` and `$sa` - not need.

Comment: @DaniDind You can share your solution as an answer for helping others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function token-run($processPath)
{
    $run = @"
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

public struct ProcessInformation
{
    public IntPtr process;
    public IntPtr thread;
    public int    processId;
    public int    threadId;
}

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int    Length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool   bInheritHandle;
}


public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL 
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="DuplicateTokenEx",SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel, int TokenType, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $run -Namespace "token" -Name "run"
$si = New-Object token.run+STARTUPINFO
$si.cb = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($si)
$pi = New-Object token.run+ProcessInformation
[uint32]$GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000
$htoken = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Token
$DupToken = New-Object System.IntPtr
$sa = New-Object token.run+SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
$sa.Length = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($sa)
$CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010
[token.run]::DuplicateTokenEx($htoken,$GENERIC_ALL,[ref]$sa,[token.run+SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL]::SecurityImpersonation,1,[ref]$DupToken)|Out-Null
[token.run]::CreateProcessWithTokenW($DupToken,0,$processPath,$null,$CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,[System.IntPtr]::Zero,"c:\windows\system32",[ref]$si,[ref]$pi)|Out-Null
}
```

This is the fixed code.
I read in some other questions that when creating a process using CreateProcess function you have to give him an lpCurrentDirectory because powershell don't know how to handle it if it is null.
Thank you very much all for your answers, hope it will help others!!!

Comment: Yes. It works. I managed to create a function that opens files on behalf of the system, but for simplicity, I used a third-party library to get the System Token, so